# d3.js Unable to call drag on label

Tags: d3.js

Here is a [plunker](http://run.plnkr.co/913k4gWKEcLebghB/) modified from [mbostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708)

I want to make the text labels drag-able and attach a line to the circle when dragged.

`.call(drag)` works on the dots but not the labels

```
   label = container.append("g")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .selectAll(".label")
        .data(dots)
      .enter().append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.x + d.y; })
        .attr("x", function(d) {return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) {return d.y; })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .call(drag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JSFiddle I made to demonstrate draggable text labels in D3.js

https://jsfiddle.net/h1n6fuwr/

Essentially you want to define the following variables/functions:

```
const drag = d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function(d) { return d; })
  .on("dragstart", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("dragend", dragended)

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}

function dragged(d) {
  const elem = d3.select(this)
  elem.attr('x', +elem.attr('x') + d3.event.dx)
  elem.attr('y', +elem.attr('y') + d3.event.dy)
}

function dragended(d) {}
```

And then call `.call(drag)` on your text labels.

```
const labels = ['Drag Me1', 'Drag Me2', 'Drag Me3']

d3.select('svg')
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(labels)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .text(d => d)
  .attr('fill', 'green')
  .attr('x', (d, i) => 10 + i*30)
  .attr('y', (d, i) => 15 + i*30)
  .call(drag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a `rect` behind the `text`, then `.call(drag)` on your rect.  To get a suitable `rect`, you can use [`text.getBBox()`](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, can you put up a jsfiddle or something? thanks.